# How to stack multiple images with one image

Tags: html

I have image folders like body,collar,sleeves and cuffs and inside there i have images. Actually I have four images I want stack all these images together in their places.

Below is my html,

```html
<div id="myJershy">
    <img src="image/Pngs/collar/White.png" id="grey" style="position: fixed; top: 8px; left: 12px; width: 935px;">
    <img class="orange" id="orange" src="image/Pngs/body/White.png" style="position: fixed; left: 10px; top: 8px;">
    <img src="image/Pngs/sleeves/White.png" id="gold" style="position: fixed; top: 12px; left: 22px;">
    <img class="back" id="black" src="image/Pngs/cuffs/White.png" style="position: fixed; left: 11px; top: 9px;"> 
</div>
```

How to make that div images together. Please help me someone.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to automatically load all images from a certain file? I suggest you use jQuery or PHP for that. Also, you should create just one folder with those images if you want to load them all at once.

Comment: Actually its tshirts got segmented collar, cuffs, body and sleeves and I want to put these to make one image this is what I want.

Comment: So you want to have four separate images you want to position so that it looks like one whole image? You are already doing that by adding positions to the individual images. I don't see what this has to do with images being in different folders?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all images on the very same position and put them "together", you could simply do this:

```css
#myJershy img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="myJershy">
    <img src="image/Pngs/collar/White.png" id="grey">
    <img class="orange" id="orange" src="image/Pngs/body/White.png">
    <img src="image/Pngs/sleeves/White.png" id="gold">
    <img class="back" id="black" src="image/Pngs/cuffs/White.png"> 
</div>
```

However, if you want everything to be at different locations, I'd if possible recommend using a tool such as Paint.net, Gimp or Photoshop to put them together there instead. If that is not possible however, you got yourself a challenge as you'll need to use absolute locations like you have tried yourself.